# How to use "if statements" in "let" statements in xquery

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, xquery-3.0

I wish to do the following:

```
let $foo :=
    if (5 = 5)
    then
        return <bye/>
    else
        return <hi/>
```

But unfortunately the above doesn't work.

How do I do if statments for let statements.

Comment: It's the "return" that's the problem. Deleting the "saxon" tag as there is nothing here that's specific to Saxon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to do something like:

```
let $foo :=
    if (5 = 5) then
        <bye/>
    else
        <hi/>
```

then you can return the result with

```
return
  $foo
```

I suggest you download basex editor from http://files.basex.org/releases/latest/ in order to test any xquery. It's fast, and can highlight errors for you.

Also take a look at http://xqdoc.org/xquery-style.html for examples on writing clean xquery code.

Comment: Thanks. Realised the `return` should be in FLOWR statements. Not XML on it's own